# LibreOffice Calc and Pivot table with empty cells

Tags: pivot-table, libreoffice-calc, limesurvey

I want to process survey results with LibreOffice Calc (for example with data coming from LimeSurvey).

Since some questions were optional, some cells are empty (like `A6`):

[image: LibreOffice screenshot columns]

I want to answer questions like:

- How many people have given the answer `2`?
- How many people did not respond?

So, I've created a pivot table with `Insert` → `Pivot`:

[image]

but... I was not able to answer the question "How many people did not respond?" (see `B6`).

[image: LibreOffice pivot table screenshot empty]

Actual bug:

- the cell `B6` counting empty cells **is empty**

Expected result:

- the cell `B6` counting empty cells should be `1` (sum of empty cells = `1`)

To fix this problem I have a workaround consisting in creating a "temporary table" and replacing empty cells with something weird like `§ EMPTY VALUE §` to then be able to analyze empty values with my pivot table.

How do you handle empty cells in LibreOffice Calc with a pivot table?

I can reproduce this problem on LibreOffice 6.4.7 on Debian GNU/Linux, on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa and on other operating systems.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround:

in column B, transform column A to string (the formula for cell B2 is `=""&A2`)

Then create the pivot table using the values in column B.

Answer (score 0):

It seems LibreOffice has a known bug since 2012, involving pivot tables with empty cells.

https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47523

AFAIK, the described workaround, involving a temporary table, is the only known solution.

Note: since 2022 it seems there is an available patch under review that you can check:

- https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/c/core/+/129088

Update 2023: the patch was abandoned and the bug is still there.